# PHP - DOM - get text with tags

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to get all the content (text+tags) from a string which looks like that:

```
'<div id='1' data-AAA='something1' data-BBB='something2'><em>My</em></div>
<div id='5' data-AAA='something5' data-BBB='something6'><span style='color:red;'>Web</span></div>
    ...'
```

When I do that:

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($value);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $ST) {
             $valueSub = $Sub->nodeValue;
             var_dump($valueSub);
        }die;
```

I get this :

```
string 'My' (length=2)
string 'Web' (length=3)
```

But What I expect is the same but with tags which wrap the text in each `div` like this:

```
string '<em>My</em>' (length=2)
string '<span style='color:red;'Web</span>' (length=3)
```

how can I do please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code using `XPath`:

```
$string = <<<EOF
<div id='1' data-AAA='something1' data-BBB='something2'><em>My</em></div>
<div id='5' data-AAA='something5' data-BBB='something6'><span style='color:red;'>Web</span></div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Select the parent elements of text nodes somewhere
// in div elements
foreach($selector->query('//div//text()/..') as $node) {
    var_dump($doc->saveHTML($node));
}
```

**Output:**

```
string(11) "<em>My</em>"
string(35) "<span style="color:red;">Web</span>"
```